# Access a div inside ListView in codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a div with id="myDiv" and runat="server" inside a listview with id="lvItem".I need to access the div in code behind to add width of the div at runtime.How can I access the div from codebehid using C#?Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an Asp:Panel instead. Asp:Panel in ASP.NET = DIV on the front end.

So basically this would be your code

**ASP.NET**

```
<asp:Panel id="myDiv" runat="server">
</asp:Panel>
```

**Code Behind**

```
Panel myDiv = (Panel)myListView.FindControl("myDiv");
myDiv.Attributes.Add("style", "width: 100px");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div id="coolmenu" runat="server">
 </div>   

 HtmlControl htmlDivControl = (HtmlControl)Page.FindControl("coolmenu");
 (htmlDivControl.Style["width"]) ="30px";
```